# Java / Android HTML custom tag parser

Tags: java, android, html-parsing, jsoup, jericho-html-parser

I'm trying to figure out a way to parse a html file with custom tags in the form:

```
[custom tag="id"]
```

Here's an example of a file I'm working with:

```
<p>This is an <em>amazing</em> example. </p>
<p>Such amazement, <span>many wow.</span> </p>
<p>Oh look, a wild [custom tag="amaze"] appears.</p>
We need maor embeds <a href="http://youtu.be/F5nLu232KRo"> bro
```

What I would like (in an ideal world) is to get back is a list of elements):

```
List foundElements = [text, custom tag, text, link, text]
```

Where the element in the above list contains:

**Text:**

```
<p>This is an <em>amazing</em> example. </p>
<p>Such amazement, <span>many wow.</span> </p>
<p>Oh look, a wild [custom tag="amaze"] appears.</p>
We need maor embeds
```

**Custom tag:**

```
[custom tag="amaze"]
```

**Link:**

```
<a href="http://youtu.be/F5nLu232KRo">
```

**Text:**

```
 appears.</p>We need maor embeds
```

What I've tried:

1. **[Jsoup](http://jsoup.org/)**
   Jsoup is great, it works perfectly for HTML. The issue is I can't define custom tags with opening "[" and closing "]". Correct me if I'm wrong?
2. **[Jericho](http://jericho.htmlparser.net/)**
   Again like Jsoup, Jericho works great..except for defining custom tags. You're [required](https://github.com/amplafi/jericho-html/blob/master/src/java/net/htmlparser/jericho/EndTagType.java#L101) to use "<".
3. **Java Regex**
   This is the option I really don't want to go for. It's not reliable and there's a lot of string manipulation that is brittle, especially when you're matching against a lot of regexes.

Last but not least, I'm looking for a performance orientated solution as this is done on an Android client.

All suggestions welcome!

Comment: I don't think you will get around the manual work here. With a combination of jsoup and regex you should get it.

Comment: Possible useful: [traverse document with a NodeVisitor](http://jsoup.org/apidocs/org/jsoup/nodes/Node.html#traverse(org.jsoup.select.NodeVisitor))

Comment: you can try with Jsoup and XML Parser: Document doc = Jsoup.parse(html, baseUri, Parser.xmlParser());

Comment: Does `[custom tag="amaze"]` close somewhere?

Comment: Nope it doesn't close. It's simply [custom tag="amaze"]  My current solution is to use a regex to replace every  [custom tag="amaze"]  with  <custom tag="amaze"/> so Jsoup can parse, but I'd like to avoid string replacements as the content the custom tags are contained within can be quite large.